# Ping Server/Domain, capure IP as variable

Tags: variables, dns, ip, ping, capture

I have a question that I cannot seem to find an answer for. With Windows, you could ping a given domain name, and capture the ip as a variable, even if no reply was recieved. I believe the command looked something like this:

```
ping domain.com for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ping /n 1 /w 1 domain.com ^| find "Pinging"') do set ipaddress=%%B"
```

This is exactly what I am trying to do with a bash script rather than a batch file. I've stumbled across alot of questions that are really close, but not quite what I am looking for. I cannot seem to figure out the best way to go about this. How can I capture IP address using bash script?

PS: I'm still fairly new to linux environment.

Comment: why not use `nslookup` or `host`? the ping hack was for older windoze versions that didn't have nslookup, e.g. win9x

Comment: Could you please explain, what exactly you are trying to achieve? You might get better responses/answers this way.

Comment: I was trying to ping a domain, and capture the servers IP as a variable for further use within the bash script, but I was having trouble isolating the single IPa that was needed. 

NSLookup was capturing all four IPa's as a single variable, but I only needed the one. Apologies, if was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pulling the answer out of the question and posting it here for future users

---

```
ip=$(ping -c 1 $input | gawk -F'[()]' '/PING/{print $2}')
```

You can use the `ip` variable in your script at this point.

As an example, when pinging `google.com` you get this result:

```
echo $(ping -c 1 google.com | gawk -F'[()]' '/PING/{print $2}')
74.125.225.96
```

And at this point the `ip` variable would contain `74.125.225.96`

Comment: Thank-you. I'm a little late, but thank you. This is what I needed.